# Font Size not reflecting in IText

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to set the font size inside my table cell but it isn't working. I am using IText 2.0.8 because it is a legacy application and cannot upgrade to the later versions.

I tried using a phrase inside the paragraph and setting the font there as well but it isn't getting reflected in the generated PDF.

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
PdfPTable innerTable = new PdfPTable(TWO);
BaseFont bf1 = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.COURIER_BOLDOBLIQUE,
        BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
BaseFont bf2 = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.TIMES_BOLDITALIC,
        BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(key + ": ", new Font(bf1, 30));
PdfPCell innerCell = new PdfPCell(paragraph);
innerCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
innerTable.addCell(innerCell);
paragraph = new Paragraph(value, new Font(bf2, 30));
innerCell = new PdfPCell(paragraph);
innerCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
innerTable.addCell(innerCell);
cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
cell.addElement(innerTable);
cell.setFixedHeight(FIXED_HEIGHT);
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you have a look,

```
Font font = new Font(BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.COURIER_BOLDOBLIQUE,
            BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED), 30, Font.BOLD, new Color(0, 0, 0));
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(key + ": ", font);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot this worked. Have been stuck on this since yesterday :)

Comment: Hi had another question related to iText, I added an image to a PdfPCell. The image is getting resized based on fixed height of cell. However, the image borders appear on the older width of the image. Why is this happening? Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: Image Borders is not appearing, or a Resize Problem ??